# Python: How to do this string manipulation

Tags: python

Folks,
Might find this on searching, but need this rather quickly done:

I have the path like this: /mnt/path1/path2/path3/

I need to chown all the directories such as /mnt, /mnt/path1, /mnt/path1/path2, /mnt/path1/path2/path3, how to get this done in python?

I cannot do 'chown -R /mnt/' since it tries to chown all the files/directories that exist beneath path3, but I wish to chown only upto path3 here for example.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: So, your question is how to split the string up into paths? Or is it how to do a chown operation from Python?

Comment: Sorry, should've been clearer. I am looking for a way to get all those paths so I could chown them in a single command: "chown <username> /mnt /mnt/path1 /mnt/path1/path2 /mnt/path1/path2/path3

Comment: @Jkerian: Yes, I need to do so in python. And further, find . -type d would find all dirs, while I need to chown only the paths supplied one by one, not all directories within it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
>>> import os
>>> path = "abc/def/ghi"
>>> a = path.split("/")
>>> [os.path.join(*a[:i]) for i in range(1, len(a)+1)]
['abc', 'abc/def', 'abc/def/ghi']
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick 'n' dirty:

```
stop = '/mnt/path1/path2/path3'
for (dir, subdirs, files) in os.walk('/mnt'):
    if dir[:len(stop)] != stop:
        for x in [os.path.join(dir, f) for f in files] + [dir]:
           os.chown(x, uid, gid)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `os.path` library. If you start off with directory `d` then `os.path.abspath(os.path.join(d, '..'))` will return that directory's parent. You do this until you get to `/mnt`, for each directory running `chown` on it.